# Why was my comment flag declined?

Tags: support, flags, meta, declined-flags, comment-flags

I flagged a comment on [this answer](/a/281831#281831) as "Too Chatty". From my flagging history, I don't know *which* comment, but probably the following:

> That certainly helps, thanks.

Yet, a few days later, it was declined with no reason given. It's an obviously chatty comment that really doesn't say much. So why was it declined? Did Tim Post lose his keys again? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was declined but maybe you should have flagged all three comments as Obsolete. Only the last comment is still relevant.

Comment: @rene why can't you flag them yourself?

Comment: I'm not bothered by those comments. I didn't want to write an answer so I left a comment for you. This becomes chatty quickly though.

Comment: It's kind of a useful comment...I mean it lets followers know the previous comment resolved something anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to note that declining a flag doesn't always mean you raised the wrong flag. Sometimes, it means the moderator who reviewed your flag doesn't agree with you and it doesn't necessarily represent all other moderators' view.

> It's an obviously chatty comment that really doesn't say much.

Well, it depends on how you interpret the word [*chatty*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chatty). According to the linked Merriam-Webster dictionary, it means

> 1. tending to talk a lot : fond of chatting
> 2. having an informal style that is similar to friendly speech

The comment you flagged doesn't seem to belong to either of them and I don't agree with your saying "that really doesn't say much." because

1. @DavidZ posted a comment suggesting an edit.
2. The OP responded to the comment and edited the answer.
3. In response to the edit, @DavidZ basically said, "*Your edited answer reads more clear and helpful to me than the answer before the edit, thanks.*"

I don't think it is too chatty. Of course, we are discouraged to say just "thanks" in the comment, but I don't see any problem with responding to an edit with "That certainly helps, thanks".

To me, *too chatty* will apply to comments that don't add anything meaningful to a post and sound like a discussion that has nothing to do with the post. Again, others might differ.

Comment: You'd think those flags would be "disputed" but whatever.

Comment: If anything, those three comments are obsolete.  The first two are upvoted which might require a custom flag instead as moderators, specially on meta, tend to decline flags for up voted comments to prevent being accused of silencing opposing voices.

Comment: @rene Who would accuse you of silencing opposing voices? I think a flagged comment should be taken care of according to the principles and guidelines regardless of the number of upvotes,

Comment: The user who's up voted comment is deleted and the users who upvoted. I would general agree with your take on it but on META mods are and should be more careful in their actions and on MSE even more so because it does not have elected moderators, only SE staff.